# Is "research" as a countable noun actually used by native speakers?

Tags: academia, non-native-english, research

I see this phrase being used often by non-native speakers, and it never fails to strike me as incorrect:

```
"In this research, [...]"
```

I also note that [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/researches) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/research) consider that usage correct, but "rare" and "formal + old-fashioned". [This Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Research-is-an-uncountable-noun-but-why-does-it-have-a-plural-form) has a comment that says that it is restricted to British English, too, but there are no sources for this. Searching for occurrences of this usage on Google is hard, because "researches" could also be the verb, and "a research" is usually followed by "paper" or "group".

So, is research as a countable noun really used by native speakers, or has it already fallen out of usage and is only kept alive by awkward translations?

Comment: In your quote, *research* is an abstract mass noun, and perfectly normal. A countable example would be "In these researches"; "I did a number of researches" (which does sound distinctly odd, formal and old-fashioned).

Comment: Yes it is, and it is a common expression in wring too: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+this+research+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20this%20research%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 But look what happens when you change the target to [*in these researches*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+these+researches&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20these%20researches%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: In the plural it is an expression that I hear in sentences like "recent researches on Mediaeval History/cancer/the theory of etc.,"  so in formal contexts. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=researches+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresearches%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Your example *In this research* is probably not the best one, because it could be either countable, or uncountable. Perhaps you want to write *In these researches*?

Comment: Using *research* as an uncountable noun to refer to a body of research work is perfectly normal in the US, including formal technical papers.  I think that the only times I've seen the plural form has been when reading comments online from what were obviously from E2L writers.  "In these researches" would be quite "odd".

Comment: @HotLicks It is (perfectly normal) in Britain too. I'm not clear where Josh is hearing *researches*. If I saw it I would assume the person was a non- native speaker.

Comment: You do not give an example of a count usage. The test is whether numerals can correctly be inserted ('In these 2 / 6 / 100 researches' ... and they can't. But there is something of an anomaly here – as with 'in this work' there is an understood if indefinite deletion. ' ... in the undertaking of this research' / 'among the discoveries made in the undertaking of this research [+ adjustment]' / 'in the body of this work' ....

Comment: Sorry to bump this ancient thread, but you seem to have misread your own sources. Merriam-Webster says that the *plural form* “researches” is “formal + old-fashioned”, and you have linked to the Wiktionary entry for the plural form “researches”. Neither of them says that there is anything uncommon about “In this research, …” — which, as @Araucaria says, is ambiguous in terms of countability. (“There are fish *in this **pond**”* is countable; “there are chemicals *in this **water**”* is uncountable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to refer to a non-specific general study as "research", it doesn't need to be pluralized as the word "research" itself can mean it as an abstract noun.

When it is difficult to find usages for a word which can be used as "noun" and "verb" at the same time such as "research", you could consider searching it as a "subject" in a passive sentence:

"research has been done" vs "researches have been done" in Ngram Viewer.

[image]

There could be a situation where more than one ***piece of*** research has been done. For example, "A research" using monkeys as a guinea pig, "B research" using mice, "C research" using pigs. Then, the mass noun "research" is pluralized in:

> These three ***researches*** have shown that the medicine is safe for a
>   test on human.

or

> All ***research*** has shown that the medicine is safe for a test on human.

In the second example, you don't need to pluralize "research" as the usage of "researches" indicates below.

[image]

You could consider using "piece of" to express the number of researches, but using "3 pieces of research" in the above second example doesn't seem to be ideal as it is not concise and you can pluralize "research".

[image]

You could see the plural form is rarely used in "the research on" vs "the researches on"

[image]

Comment: While this answer contains useful tips on using Ngram viewer to answer this question, I feel like it does not really answer it, so I hesitate to accept.

Comment: @FvD You don't need to accept an answer.